WP Cron is not running
I have disabled WP Cron using wp-config.php file because I need my custom tasks to run exactly on the hour. So my crontab file has this line to run the wp-cron on the hour
0 * * * * wget --delete-after https://wp.nextlabs.us/wp-cron.php
Hope this is correct. But i found out that this doesn't run as expected. My wp-cron.php file's permissions are -rw-rw-r-- .
Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

if you request the url in a browser, do the tasks run as expected ?

@mmm Thanks bro for the response. It is working now as expected.
